# Loading content and apply a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I'm loading some content to the index of my webpage with ajax, I have some click function to apply to those content, the problem is that click event just work if I load the content manual, if i use ajax it doesn't work for the content loaded with it, It looks like I got to tell the site that there's new content but i don't know how.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: use click event like this `$(document).on('click', 'your id or class', function(){});`

Comment: @Kathiravan One question, what if I got a .bind ended event, how i would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do  [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements.

Ex:

```
$('containerId').on('click','elementId',function(){

//do something

})
```

where

```
containerId  //To which you added the elements

elementId  //on which you are doing the click event.
```

`$(document).on(.....` also works but selecting more specific element increases the performance.

Comment: One question, what if I got .bind ended event, how i would do it/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `on` Method of jquery. [Jquery On()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

```
$('#yourID').on('click','context',function(){

//do something

})
```

Comment: One question, what if I got a .bind ended event, how i would do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'your id or class', function(){
   //ur action here
});
```

Comment: One question, what if I got a .bind ended event, how i would do it?

Answer (score 0):

Search the keyword: javascript event delegate .

You can use event delegate  or bind event after load the new content .

Answer (score 0):

The click event maybe defined in the #id or .class or an element which is dyanamically added to the page via ajax.

What you have to realise is that the function gets executed on page load and at that time, the particular element(#id or .class) wont be there and hence you are not able to execute the click function.

Check your browser console and you might get the undefined error.